# Fetching avatars from gravatar with gitg behind an authenticated proxy

Tags: git, proxy, ldap

I'm still a bit new to git, and I use gitg to visualize trees.

It works quite well (I managed to make it crash on some big projects, but never mind), and I saw on Windows computers that it displays gravatars when committers have one.

I have seen this feature working on a virtual Ubuntu (Ubuntu guest in a Virtual Box on a Windows Seven host), displaying these gravatars.

The problem seems to be that my machine is behind an LDAP-authenticated proxy (I need to tell it my domain\username:password in order to connect).

I run a 11.10 Ubuntu on my machine, installed my own squid in order to type my login/password in only one place, and, when gitg tries to retrieve these avatars, I get the following error :
** (gitg:9452): WARNING **: avatar_cache_open_cb: Cannot resolve proxy hostname

(This is ubuntu's version of gitg : 0.2.4-0ubuntu1 ).

I've thoroughly looked on the internet before asking this question (thoroughly meaning 2 or 3 days of Googling and following links within mailing lists), so, if someone has any idea, this would help me :)

(I tried to install libproxy-simple, as stated in this page : http://felipec.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/getting-proxy-support-on-gnome-for-real-libproxy-simple/, but this didn't change anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your proxy is accepting only NTLM authentication (which is very common on windows SSO), you may use a NTLM authenticating proxy (e.g. [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)). It is a "proxy-to-proxy" that do the authentication for you.

Comment: Yup, that's what I do, using squid. gitg uses squid as its "proxy-to-proxy" solution, with no credential at all (or at least I would like it to), on localhost:3128